# To create the Sample Sheet(.csv) for idat files

Tags: r, bioinformatics, illumina

I am trying to analyze Differentially Methylated Genes based on the ChAMP package on GEO data (GSE166427). Although, I want to know how should I produce the "Sample Sheet.csv" file to do my analysis because there is no  samplesheet file between downloaded files, and the file names are like these :

```
[1] "GSM3759532_CLX_Methylation_A2004_N"   "GSM3759533_CLX_Methylation_A2004_T"  
[3] "GSM3759534_CLX_Methylation_A2027_N"   "GSM3759535_CLX_Methylation_A2027_T"  
[5] "GSM3759536_CLX_Methylation_A2050_N"   "GSM3759537_CLX_Methylation_A2050_T"
```

So, I can not deal with the required columns, Sentrix_ID, Sentrix_Position, etc.

Is there any function or package to prepare the samplesheet.csv file automatically??